# g++ error: Cannot specify -static with -fsanitize=address

Tags: g++

I am trying to use address sanitizer with g++ and during the build it produces the following linker command, which produces the error `g++: error: cannot specify -static with -fsanitize=address`

I don't understand what this means, so any help is appreciated. The g++ version is `g++ (GCC) 8.3.0 20190222 (Cray Inc.)`.

```
g++ -g -fsanitize=address   CMakeFiles/pisa.dir/src/Alphabet.cpp.o {more .o files}  -o pisa  -L/global/homes/e/esaliya/sali/git/bitbucket/combinatorial-blas-2.0/CombBLAS/_install/lib -Wl,-rpath,/global/homes/e/esaliya/sali/git/bitbucket/combinatorial-blas-2.0/CombBLAS/_install/lib -lCombBLAS -lGraphGenlib -lUsortlib
```